# Install Canon TS9120 in wifi mode

Tags: 20.04, scanner, ubuntu-mate

Since I can not get my scanner to work using a cable with Ubuntu Mate 20.04, I would like to learn how to install it in wifi mode.

This is what is presented when I want to add the Canon TS9120 printer/scanner.

[image]

Comment: here is how it is done on your printer/scanner https://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/TS9100%20series/EN/UG/ug_p_02_01_03.html remember to print out the setup page if you are prompted to do so.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But this is turning to a nightmare. I followed the instructions and entered the password to connect. It disconnected. And I can not use it as a printer either. @trond hansen

Comment: sorry to hear this,it looks to me like a lot of people have this problem in ubuntu 20.04 with several brands of printers.several bug reports have been made about this problem and printers did work fine under ubuntu before so the devs should know how to make it work again.this problem excludes a huge number of people and companies from using ubuntu 20.04,ubuntu 20.04 is still on hold as an upgrade from 18.04 so the problem might get a fix before ubuntu looses too many users from this.

Comment: @trond hansen I agree with you. There are other things about 20.04 that are just as frustrating. Maybe some future updates will fix those issues.